# Raspbian NFS parent folder permissions

Tags: permissions, nfs, version

I have a Raspberry Pi booting over network (NFS share). This works fine. But depending on the NFS version I use (tried 3 and 2) there is a weird behavior concerning permissions of parent folder. Here is an example:

Parent folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    42 Jun 21 15:07 /opt
```

Subfolder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 user1 group1 712 Jun 21 15:19 /opt/subfolder
```

Simple nodejs script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

try {
  fs.accessSync('/opt/subfolder', fs.constants.W_OK);
  console.log('accessible');
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

The script is executed as "user1". When I configure the NFS protocol version 2 in `cmdline.txt` this script outputs `accessible`. If I use version 3 then I get an `access denied` error. When booting the Pi from SD card then everything works also as expected. So it seems there is something different with NFS version 3.

Is somebody able to point me into the right direction what needs to be changed?

Thanks!

Comment: What is different in the NFS configuration (exports from server, mounting by client) when you use v2 vs. when you use v3 of the NFS protocol?

Comment: Is `/opt/subfolder` part of the `/opt` export, or is it a separate (subtree) export? Can you share the relevant line(s) from the server's `exports` file?

Comment: Sorry for answering late. Here is the line from my exports file: /volume1/root    192.168.X.9(rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100). The "opt" folder is a subfolder of the nfs mount. "subfolder" is a direct child of "opt". Thanks!